# Python3 Client/Server Issues

Tags: python

Morning all, i'm having trouble with my basic server/client program below, after i run both scripts on 2 separate IDLE(python) windows, the client successfully connects to the server, and is able to send the first message (eg hello), which on the server side is translated as "b'hello'", but i cannot respond from the server to the client again, i get the error:

s.send(conn, str(reply).encode('utf-8'))
TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not socket

SERVER:

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8019
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, address = s.accept()
print("Connected to", address)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print("Recieved :", repr(data))
    reply = input("Reply :")
    s.send(conn, str(reply).encode('utf-8'))

conn.close()
```

CLIENT:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',8019))
while True:
    message = input("Your Message: ")
    s.send(bytes(message,"ascii"))
    print("Awaiting the reply...")
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    print("Recieved ", str(reply))



s.close()
```

My questions are as follows, how do i send a string back to my client program? and how do i read the string as sent from the client without the "b''" formatting

(on a side note every time i restart the server i need to change the port on both client and server program, am i not closing the ports properly after use?)

Answer (score 0):

First off, when a socket accepts a client `socket.accept()` it returns two values.
The first being a new socket that is created and is used to communicate with the connecting side (client).

In your server code, you supply the client socket as an argument, which should raise and error. You need only supply, the data to send.

```
s.send(conn, str(reply).encode('utf-8'))
```

You should use the client socket to send your data.

```
conn.send( reply.encode('utf-8') )
```

Instead of using send, use `sendall()` this takes care of making sure all data gets to the other side of the connection.

When receiving data, decode using the same format that's used to encode (utf-8)

```
data = conn.recv(4069).decode('utf-8')
```

I have edited your code

#### Server

```
import socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 8019
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1) # Number of connections

# Server loop
while True:
    # Accept connections
    client, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to", address)

    # Receive data and decode using utf-8
    data = client.recv( 1024 ).decode( 'utf-8' )
    print("Recieved :", repr(data))

    # Send data to client in utf-8
    reply = input("Reply :")
    client.sendall( reply.encode('utf-8') ) # Make sure data gets there with sendall()


s.close()
```

### Client

```
import socket

# Create socket and connect it to server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost',8019))

# client loop
while True:
    message = input("Your Message: ")
    s.send( message.encode('utf-8') )
    print("Awaiting the reply...")
    reply = s.recv( 1024 ).decode( 'utf-8' )
    print("Recieved ", str(reply))



s.close()
```